# Get UIView rotation angle properly in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I'm able to rotate and get rotates angle but it was not satisfies my need.
I've created view and rotation button as shown in below. 
[image]

I'm able to rotate 90 degress on each tap on rotate button as below.[image]

Now i want to print rotation angle of a view interms of degrees 0, 90, 180, 270, 360 should print as 0, and then same as 90, 180, 270, 0 has to print in place of 360..repeat based on direction.

Here is the code which i used to create below.

```
    @IBOutlet weak var myView: UIView!
@IBAction func rotateBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    myView.transform = myView.transform.rotated(by: .pi/2)
     getRotateAngle()
}
func getRotateAngle(){
    //This is just to print rotation angle of a view
    let radians = atan2(myView.transform.b, myView.transform.a)
    let degrees = radians * 180 / .pi
    print("Degrees:: \(degrees)")
}
```

And it's printing in console like below screen.
[image]

How can i got 0, 90, 180, 270, 0, 90, 180, 270, 0 degrees of a view can somebody please suggest. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First `round` your `degrees` and then calculate real degrees

```
func getRotateAngle() {
    let radians = atan2(myView.transform.b, myView.transform.a)
    var degrees = radians * 180 / .pi
    degrees.round()
    let realDegrees = degrees >= 0 ? abs(degrees) : 360 + degrees
    print("Degrees:: \(realDegrees)")
}
```

Comment: Hi Robert i got small change in requirement those details i mentioned in extension to above question. Can you please look over it and give me your valuable reply. Thank you.

Comment: @MIOSY these details werent in your question. This is different question. Edit your question to prebious question and if you have another, ask new question

Comment: yeah i thought to keep separate question but my ask question limit is exceeded in statckoverflow i can't able to write another question. can you please reply back to the question with saveTapped button action block inside required code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MIOSY so, you should ask the new question and accept answer which helped you.

Comment: Yeah i posted as another question robert and your reply marked as answer. please look over this question(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55123927/reset-view-rotation-angle-to-zero-in-swift-ios). Thank you.